# Can't connect to MySQL server (111) even after changing bind-address

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-python

I wrote a few lines of code that sends data to a remote MySQL database.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("MyServerIP","MyUserName","MYPwd","MyDB")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable(Column1) VALUES (Value1);")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server (111)

I tried:

- Putting in comment: bind-address: **Doesn't work.**
- Changed bind-address initial value to my server IP: **Doesn't work.**

Any help?

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line?

Comment: UPDATE: Actually no. When I try to connect remotely to the mysql Database, Same error on the console!